# PhpStorm git merging branch without conflicts

Tags: git, merge, phpstorm, diff, git-diff

I have two remote and local branches: `master` and `refactor`. I want to merge `refactor` branch into `master` and review all changes in PhpStorm's diff tool with 3 windows.

My problem is that PhpStorm says that there are no conflicts (`refactor` branch is same as `master` but 5 commits ahead) and merges branches automatically so I can't review code and fix any bugs in it.

It this possible to specify branch merging disabling auto-merge (when there are no conflicts). Google and PhpStorm help didn't help me.

Comment: There are no conflicts! Nice! If you want to merge without completing it (to check it or whatever), you can use the `—no-commit` option.

Comment: Yes, there are no conflicts, but there are still can be bugs - for example in one place was removed ! sign, and git decided that there are no conflict, so I want to review such moments.
Option —no-commit  doesnt activate diff tool and I cant review changes

Comment: You can do that all manually. Git can’t prevent bugs. Do you perform code reviews?

Comment: I want to make code review when I have merge request (for example as in gitlab), so I want to review code while merging branches and edit it if smth wrong

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to review a merge commit that was just created (automatically, because there was no conflict) is the check the content of said commit.

See JetBrains "[Review changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/viewing-changes-information.html)", and the [log tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/log-tab.html) to select the last merge commit.

If your review reveals some bugs, you can then fix said bugs and make a new commit on top of the merge commit.

Comment: PhpStorm has window with "apply left, apply right" where I can review changes and edit some bugs or change some code. But how can I both compare branches and edit code together if there are non-conflict merge?
For example, I can both view and edit code using gitlab WEB IDE, and I expected phpstotm has this functionallity

Comment: @playerro I don't know, which is why I suggested doing the review after the merge is (automatically) completed. BUt I understand this is less convenient.

Answer (score 0):

> refactor branch is same as master but 5 commits ahead

This is a fast-forward merge then, which is in fact just moving `master` reference. There will be no additional commits at all, and no conflicts.

> It this possible to specify branch merging disabling auto-merge

It is possible with the `--no-commit` option. This, however, will not open any merge tool for you - just the changes from the merged branch will stay uncommitted in the working copy. You will be able to review them with 2-side diff.

Comment: But reviewing 2-side diff I can not edit some code, so I should keep both 2-side diff and editor

Comment: In any case, with 2 side diff or 3-side diff/merge, you can only edit the version in your working tree. Moreover, one side of the 3-way diff will have no difference with the central pane if there are no conflicts.

Comment: I understand that it has no difference between my pane, but I want to make them! I had such case: git merged with no conflicts file where was if(condition) replaced on if(!condition). So I want to compare both branched and edit one at center pane. Same functionallity there are in gitlab while resolving merge request